# unique words by group

Tags: r, aggregate, unique, lapply

this is my example dataframe

```
example = data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "A", "A"), word = c("car", "sun ,sun, house", "car, house", "tree"))
```

I would like to get only unique words within group and through groups

So I would like to get this

```
group   word
A       car, tree
B       sun
```

I used aggregate and get this

```
aggregate(word ~ group , data = example,  FUN = paste0) 

  group                  word
1     A car, car, house, tree
2     B       sun ,sun, house
```

but now i need to select only unique values, but even this does not work out

```
for (i in 1:nrow(cluster)) {cluster[i, ][["word"]] = lapply(unlist(cluster[i, ][["word"]]), unique)}
```

with

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "word", value = list("car", "car, house",  : 
  replacement has 3 rows, data has 1
```

Comment: So you want to remove words that appear on both groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A base R option using `aggregate` + `subset` + `ave` like below

```
with(
  aggregate(
    word ~ .,
    example,
    function(x) {
      unlist(strsplit(x, "[, ]+"))
    }
  ),
  aggregate(
    . ~ ind,
    subset(
      unique(stack(setNames(word, group))),
      ave(seq_along(ind), values, FUN = length) == 1
    ),
    c
  )
)
```

gives

```
  ind    values
1   A car, tree
2   B       sun
```

Comment: @GKi Thanks! Really good point to improve the code :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `dplyr` solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
example %>% 
  separate_rows(word) %>% 
  distinct(group, word) %>% 
  group_by(word) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(word = toString(word))
```

output

```r
  group word       
1 A     car, tree
2 B     sun
```

Comment: The separate_rows() function seems to be included in 'tidyr' package.

Comment: much more concise than my base R option :), like it, +1!

Answer (score 2):

In *base* you can use `strsplit` to get the words, `split` them by *group* and use `unique` the get unique words per group. Use `table` to get the number of same words and take those which appear only once.

```
t1 <- lapply(split(strsplit(example$word, "[, ]+"), example$group),
               \(x) unique(unlist(x)))
t2 <- table(unlist(t1))
t2 <- names(t2)[t2 == 1]
t1 <- lapply(t1, \(x) paste(x[x %in% t2], collapse = ", "))
data.frame(group = names(t1), word=unlist(t1))
#  group      word
#A     A car, tree
#B     B       sun
```

Or another way starting with the already used `aggregate` in the question.

```
t1 <- aggregate(word ~ group , data = example,  FUN = toString)
t2 <- lapply(strsplit(t1$word, "[, ]+"), unique)
t3 <- table(unlist(t2))
t3 <- names(t3)[t3 == 1]
t1$word <- lapply(t2, \(x) x[x %in% t3])
t1
#  group      word
#1     A car, tree
#2     B       sun
```

And just for fun a **Benchmark**

```
library(bench)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidyverse)

example = data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "A", "A"), word = c("car", "sun ,sun, house", "car, house", "tree"))

bench::mark(check = FALSE,
GKi = {t1 <- lapply(split(strsplit(example$word, "[, ]+"), example$group),
               \(x) unique(unlist(x)))
t2 <- table(unlist(t1))
t2 <- names(t2)[t2 == 1]
t1 <- lapply(t1, \(x) paste(x[x %in% t2], collapse = ", "))
data.frame(group = names(t1), word=unlist(t1))},
GKi2 = {t1 <- aggregate(word ~ group , data = example,  FUN = toString)
t2 <- lapply(strsplit(t1$word, "[, ]+"), unique)
t3 <- table(unlist(t2))
t3 <- names(t3)[t3 == 1]
t1$word <- lapply(t2, \(x) x[x %in% t3])
t1},
ThomasIsCoding = with(
  aggregate(
    word ~ .,
    example,
    function(x) {
      unlist(strsplit(x, ", "))
    }
  ),
  aggregate(
    . ~ ind,
    subset(
      unique(stack(setNames(word, group))),
      ave(seq_along(ind), values, FUN = length) == 1
    ),
    c
  )
),
Mael = {example %>% 
  separate_rows(word) %>% 
  distinct(group, word) %>% 
  group_by(word) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1) %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(word = toString(word))},
"Nir Graham" = {example <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "A", "A"),
                      word = c("car", "sun ,sun, house", "car, house", "tree"))

(sep_df <- separate_rows(example,word,sep = ",") |> mutate_all(trimws) |> distinct())

(uniq_df <- sep_df|> group_by(word) |> count() |> filter(n==1))

(result_df <- inner_join(sep_df,uniq_df) |> group_by(group) |> summarise(word=paste0(word,collapse=", ")))
}
)
```

Result

```
  expression          min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc
  <bch:expr>     <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>
1 GKi            445.13µs 486.26µs    1997.    16.03KB     6.15   974     3
2 GKi2           916.97µs 968.68µs    1023.      7.3KB     6.15   499     3
3 ThomasIsCoding   3.54ms   3.73ms     266.     8.19KB     8.45   126     4
4 Mael            16.07ms  16.48ms      60.1   60.04KB     6.68    27     3
5 Nir Graham      37.29ms  39.49ms      24.0   90.59KB     8.00     9     3
```

GKi is about 2 times faster than GKi2, 7 times faster than ThomasIsCoding, 30 than Mael and 80 than Nir Graham.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

example <- data.frame(group = c("A", "B", "A", "A"),
                      word = c("car", "sun ,sun, house", "car, house", "tree"))

(sep_df <- separate_rows(example,word,sep = ",") |> mutate_all(trimws) |> distinct())

(uniq_df <- sep_df|> group_by(word) |> count() |> filter(n==1))

(result_df <- inner_join(sep_df,uniq_df) |> group_by(group) |> summarise(word=paste0(word,collapse=", ")))
```